# Git commit diff show line update in only one line

Tags: git, diff, show

I know that by using the commands

```
git show / git diff
```

I can get the line changes, nevertheless they print line modifications as a + line preceded by a - line. I recall finding somewhere an option to only show the modification in one line, with the changes printed in red (old) and green (new).

Note:

To clarify it a little, for example, by using the command `git show <commitId>` I will be getting:

```
-     <property>horses</property>
+     <property>humans</property>
```

The minus line appears in red and the plus line in green.
What I want to accomplish is to have the change in only one line, still I do not remember how the prefix appeared, but I believe it was something like:

```
+     <property>[horses]humans<property>
```

Where the whole line appears green and the word horses appears red. I know this can be done because I did it in the past with some random command I got from a page that sadly cannot remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If

```
$ git diff --word-diff=color
```

, as Peter mentioned, is not the output you want, you could try:

```
$ git diff --word-diff=plain
```

This will print some additional brackets `{}` and signs `+ -`, around the differences. But it also will show the same colorful output as `word-diff=color` will do.

To show differences per word in the 7th last commit, use:

```
$ git diff HEAD~7 --word-diff=plain
```

---

`$ git diff`

»

```
-                       // check for twice same password
+                       // check is password twice
```

---

`$ git diff --word-diff=color`

»

```
                        // check for twice sameis password twice
```

---

`$ git diff --word-diff=plain`

»

```
                        // check [-for twice same-]{+is+} password {+twice+}
```

Comment: I verified your --word-diff=plain suggestion and it worked exactly as I needed it to. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear about that. Sorry, for the late solution of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
git diff --word-diff=color
```

will show diffs using color by word.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear, I edited it to be more specific. Thanks for your answer @peter